# nodejs: Is it possible to eval js code using runInNewContext and limit its execution time by a timeout?

Tags: node.js

I'd like to execute an untrusted js code using runInNewContext in node.js but as far as I see there is no way to limit its execution time. Also it is a sync operation. is there a way to set timeout on it or async version of it that will allow me to control its execution from 'outside'?

UPDATE: running in an external process is no good:

- takes too much resources
- more importantly, I need the code to have access to my data/code though sandbox environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to execute an untrusted js code using runInNewContext in
>   node.js but as far as I see there is no way to limit its execution
>   time.  Also it is a sync operation. is there a way to set timeout on
>   it or async version of it that will allow me to control its execution
>   from 'outside'?

I think What you are saying is completely true. I think the only option is to fill an issue with [Joyent/Ryan Dahl](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues). Hopefully he/they can come up with something smart or maybe will tell you it is not possible.

From [vm.runInNewContext](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.9/api/all.html#vm.runInNewContext):

> Note that running untrusted code is a tricky business requiring great
>   care. To prevent accidental global variable leakage,
>   vm.runInNewContext is quite useful, but safely running untrusted code
>   requires a separate process.

So to do this safely you need to run in external program. I think the "expensive part" can be avoided by [preforking](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/prefork.html#how-it-works).

> A single control process is responsible for launching child processes
>   which listen for connections and serve them when they arrive. Apache
>   always tries to maintain several spare or idle server processes, which
>   stand ready to serve incoming requests. In this way, clients do not
>   need to wait for a new child processes to be forked before their
>   requests can be served.

Answer (score 1):

Run script in external process using [dnode](https://github.com/substack/dnode) or [child_process.fork](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/child_process.js#L62), set deadline timer and kill process if timeout reached or timer if script finished.

Comment: this kind of defies the purpose. I want to run lots of those and I certainly don't want to run a system process per client. also I do need to provide access to my internal functions though sandbox environment

Comment: if it's your trusted and non-blocking code then check timer flag on entering any handler and execute handler's callback passing 'timed out' error. If you can't trust the code then external process is the only option. You don't have to start process for each remote call, I don't think it's a problem

Answer (score -2):

This is now possible because I added `timeout` parameter support to the Node `vm` module. You can simply pass in a millisecond timeout value to `runInNewContext()` and it will throw an exception if the code does not finish executing in the specified amount of time.

Note, this does not imply any kind of security model for running untrusted code. This simply allows you to timeout code which you do trust or otherwise secure.

```
var vm = require("vm");

try {
    vm.runInNewContext("while(true) {}", {}, "loop", 1000);
} catch (e) {
    // Exception thrown after 1000ms
}

console.log("finished"); // Will now be executed
```

Exactly what you would expect:

```
$ time ./node test.js
finished

real    0m1.069s
user    0m1.047s
sys     0m0.017s
```